# How to convert string to array of elements in correct types

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a string to an array of elements in correct types.

An element can be either string or number.

**Example code:**

```
let str = "foo,12,hello,3.14,world,0"
let arr = str.split(",");
console.log(arr);
```

**The result I get:**

```
["foo", "12", "hello", "3.14", "world", "0"]
```

**The result I want:**

```
["foo", 12, "hello", 3.14, "world", 0]
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess you can iterate and check for isNan and then parse if yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You map it, then you check if its nan `isNaN`. If it is then its an string, otherwise its an number

```js
let str = "foo,12,hello,3.14,world,0"
let arr = str.split(",").map(item => isNaN(+item) ? item : +item);
console.log(arr)
```

If you wonder what the `+` do:

> The unary plus operator converts its operand to Number type.

If its an string it will return `NaN` and since you cannot check `NaN` like this `NaN === NaN` you need to check it with the built in method `isNaN`

```js
console.log(NaN === NaN);
console.log(NaN == NaN);
console.log(isNaN(NaN));
console.log(isNaN(+"i am an string"));
```